# Probability Repeated Games

Tags: probability

Suppose 'n' voters use the following procedure to find their leader: Each of them tosses a fair coin, a person is chosen a leader if his toss is different from other (n-1) persons' tosses. This process is iterated until a leader is found. What is the probability of finding the leader in the kth iteration?

a) $2^{1-n}[1-2^{1-n}]^{k-1}$

b) $n2^{1-n}[1-n2^{1-n}]^{k-1}$

c) $n2^{1-n}[1-2^{-n}]^{k-1}$

d) $2^{-n}[1-2^{-n}]^{k-1}$

This question was asked for 3 persons(so n=3) and the game would end in 2 iterations(so k=2). I solved the question by making the sample set. I wanted to know how this would have been answered if no. of people and no. of iterations would increase.(I just hope I did not make any mistake in generalising the question)

Comment: Why does the font size decrease?  Are there options $e,f,g,\cdots$ that are simply too small to see?

Comment: No nothing as such lulu. there are only 4 options.

Comment: Hint:  let $p$ be the probability that a winner is decided in one round.  It isn't too hard to compute $p$.  Then you just have a standard Bernoulli process with success probability $p$...you want $k-1$ failures followed by a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one round, if one person out of $n$ persons gets a result of "head" and others get "tail", then he will be chosen. We can swap "head" and "tail",
therefore in one round we will get a leader with probability $$P= 2 \times \binom{n}{1} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}.$$

The probability of finding the leader in the $k$-th iteration is $$(1-P)^{k-1} \times P = \left(1-\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{k-1} \times \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}.$$

Hence the corrcct answer is (B).

Comment: my answer is coming out to be option (C). I see no reason why you take 2 different cases (swap head and tail). Also if I use option (B), I don't get the exact answer for my case of n=3 and k=2, the answer is 15/64 by my method of drawing sample space.

Comment: Further your answer gives an answer as 3/16 which is not in any option given to me.

Comment: if n persons toss coin together sample space will $2^n$. for a specifically chosen person there are TWO ways to be leader   either he gets a HEAD and rest TAILS or he gets a TAIL and other gets HEADS. these both cases are in sample space. his probability to be leader is $\frac{2}{2^n}$   ,further you can choose a leader in $\binom{n}{1} $ ways